# How do I integrate a For loop to generate iterations of the Sierpinski's Triangle?

Tags: function-construction, linear-algebra, functional-style, procedural-programming

I'm sorry if this is a basic question—I don't know anything about programming. I know you can create a graphic of Sierpinski's Triangle with a single command, but I'd like to know how to create one with 8 iterations by "integrating a for loop" in the code I was given in my linear algebra class (for the first two iterations):

[image]

Comment: `SierpinskiMesh`

Answer (score 2):

The following code is from the help content of the `ref/AffineTransform` entry:

```
    IFS[{T__TransformationFunction}][pl_List] := Join @@ Through[{T}[pl]]
TransformIFS[g_, IFS[l_List]] := 
  Module[{prim = First[g], h = Head[g]},
   t = Table[GeometricTransformation[prim, l[[i]]], {i, Length[l]}]; 
   h[t]];
TransformIFS[g_, ifs_IFS, 0] := g;
TransformIFS[g_, ifs_IFS, 1] := TransformIFS[g, ifs];
TransformIFS[g_, ifs_IFS, n_Integer?Positive] := 
  TransformIFS[TransformIFS[g, ifs], ifs, n - 1];
SierpinskiGasket = 
  With[{\[ScriptCapitalD] = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}/2]}(*可将原图形缩小1/2*), 
   IFS[{AffineTransform[{\[ScriptCapitalD]}], 
     AffineTransform[{\[ScriptCapitalD], {1/2, 0}}],
     AffineTransform[{\[ScriptCapitalD], {1/4, Sqrt[3]/4}}]}]];
Table[TransformIFS[
  Graphics[Polygon[{{1/2, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1/2, 
      0}}]](*这里需要边长为1的三角形*), SierpinskiGasket, n], {n, 0, 5}]
```

Or

```
ruleRectangleNest[{xl_, yl_}, {xr_, yr_}, {xu_, yu_}, k_ /; k >= 1] :=
  Module[{cl = {(xl + xu)/2, (yl + yu)/2}, 
   cr = {(xr + xu)/2, (yr + yu)/2}, cd = {(xl + xr)/2, (yl + yr)/2}, 
   intI = k}, 
  If[intI <= 1, 
   Graphics@
    Triangle[{{{xu, yu}, cl, cr}, {cl, {xl, yl}, cd}, {cr, 
       cd, {xr, yr}}}], intI--; 
   Show[{ruleRectangleNest[{xu, yu}, cl, cr, intI], 
     ruleRectangleNest[cl, {xl, yl}, cd, intI], 
     ruleRectangleNest[cr, cd, {xr, yr}, intI]}]]]
ruleRectangleNest[{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, 3]
```

You can also search the community for [entry `Sierpinski`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Sierpinski) to see other people's code.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use `SierpinskiMesh` in the comment but prefer to build it from scratch ...

First, let us implement the process from one triangle to three, `triplize` in the below codes. One triangle can be represented by a $ (1\times3\times2) $-shaped data, so we need to turn it into a $ (3\times3\times2) $-shaped data, with a half scaling included. Then one needs to repeat this process $ n $ times, by using `Nest`, which I think is more suitable for iterations, and finally obtain a $ (3^n\times3\times2) $-shaped data, where $ n = 0, 1, 2, ...$.

```
Clear[sierpinski2d]
sierpinski2d[tripts_ /; Dimensions[tripts] == {1, 3, 2}, n_Integer /; n >= 0] := 
Module[{triplize, mats},
    mats = {{{1, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1/2, 0, 1/2}},
            {{1/2, 1/2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1/2}},
            {{1/2, 0, 1/2}, {0, 1/2, 1/2}, {0, 0, 1}}};
    triplize = Flatten[mats.# & /@ #, {{1, 2}}] &;
    Nest[triplize, tripts, n]
]
sierpinski2d[{CirclePoints[3]} // N, 10];
Graphics[Triangle[%]]
```

---

**Update**

Here I detail what `triplize` can do. Given the starting single group of three points $ \{\{\vec p_1, \vec p_2, \vec p_3\}\} $, which is $ (1\times3\times2) $-shaped, and note the deliberately kept first dimension. After the application, once, of `triplize` one gets three groups of three points
$$
\{\{\vec p_1, (\vec p_1 + \vec p_2)/2, (\vec p_3 + \vec p_1)/2\}, \\
\{(\vec p_1 + \vec p_2)/2, \vec p_2, (\vec p_2 + \vec p_3)/2\}, \\
\{(\vec p_3 + \vec p_1)/2, (\vec p_2 + \vec p_3)/2, \vec p_3\}\},
$$ $ (3\times3\times2) $-shaped. So it generates middle points and properly group them up.

Then for every group of three points, repeat this process.

Comment: Strange, yesterday your code can run perfectly, but today to execute your code, reported an error: `坐标$CellContext``sierpinski2d[{{{0.8660254037844386, -0.5}, {0., 1.}, {-0.8660254037844386, -0.5}}}, 10]应该是一对数值，或是Scaled或 Offset的形式`. We should use `n_NonNegativeIntegers` instead of `n_?MemberQ[NonNegativeIntegers]` to avoid reporting errors.

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas Please check this version.

Comment: This algorithm is very simple, I still don't understand the working principle, thank you.

Comment: I want to know how matrix `mats` achieves the zoom function? What's the difference between `mats` and `AffineTransform`? Can you add its working principle to the answer in detail？

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas I hope my update can facilitate understanding.

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas I believe `AffineTransform` can do the work but I do not dig into it. Also, Paul Wellin 2013 mentions `Scale` and `Translate` for a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.